# Create OpenGL context without hardware acceleration

Tags: c++, opengl

How do I force Windows/OpenGL to create a window context without hardware acceleration?

Actually I want to simulate the situation when Windows provides only software 1.1 implementation (generic microsoft one). You get such a context when you use Remote Desktop Connection (with the exception of new nVidia drivers). My code must work on such a context, so I need an ease way to test it.

I tried to play with `PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR` and its `dwFlags`. But specifying `PFD_GENERIC_FORMAT` instead of `PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL` still returns pixel format with accelerated OpenGL.

Is there any way to make life easier?

Comment: I'm not sure if this "trick" still works, but just copying the original `opengl32.dll` from `Windows/system32` (or `Windows/SysWoW64` for the 32 bit version)  to the direcotry containing the executable used to be enough to trigger a fallback to the Microsoft GDI software renderer.

Comment: Which aspect of the software rasterizer are you trying to exercise?  The slowness of software rasterization or the GL 1.1-ness?

Comment: No. I just want to `glGetString` do not return extension, `wglGetProcAddress` not return addresses, and so on